# Emulator: WARNING: Unknown AVD name

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-studio-3.0

I have installed Android studio 3.0 but once I try to run my application something goes wrong. I am on Ubuntu and the issue is to do with the path of the SDK I think.

See the error error here:

> `11:33    Emulator: WARNING: Unknown AVD name [Nexus_4_API_22], use -list-avds to see valid list.
>   11:33   Emulator: HOME is defined but there is no file Nexus_4_API_22.ini in $HOME/.android/avd
>   11:33   Emulator: (Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/avd and $HOME/.android/avd)
>   11:33   Emulator: WARNING: Unknown AVD name [Nexus_4_API_22], use -list-avds to see valid list.
>   11:33   Emulator: HOME is defined but there is no file Nexus_4_API_22.ini in $HOME/.android/avd
>   11:33   Emulator: (Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/avd and $HOME/.android/avd)
>   11:33   Emulator: WARNING: Unknown AVD name [Nexus_4_API_22], use -list-avds to see valid list.
>   11:33   Emulator: HOME is defined but there is no file Nexus_4_API_22.ini in $HOME/.android/avd
>   11:33   Emulator: (Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/avd and $HOME/.android/avd)
>   11:33   Emulator: PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
>   11:33   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1`

Comment: Check if you have write permissions on the SDK folder. I solved this problem by having the SDK on a folder with write permissions. You can always test if the emulator is working properly by running `./emulator -avd avdname` from the terminal in the `sdk/tools` folder

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue and receive the following result from `./emulator -avd avdname` with `avdname` being ` Nexus_5X_API_28_x86` in my case:
`PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.`